# Does deleting user account on macOS also deletes their installed apps?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, user-account

On a Mac with more than one user account, I can open apps installed by other users through Spotlight.

If I delete the other user accounts, will their apps get deleted too?

Answer (score 2):

On macOS, an app bundle (.app file) can technically be located anywhere. Although, in the most general case, apps are installed in the shared `/Applications` directory and in some cases in the directory with same name in the users Home directory `~/Applications` (or more completely `/Users/<username>/Applications`).

Deleting a user account deletes the users Home directory. Thus, all the app installed by user in the root `/Applications` directory remain unaffected.

Usually, when deleting a user account, macOS gives an option to preserve their Home directory contents. Any app *installed* in the Home directory can technically be carried over and used.

In short, to put it simply, since users files are hidden from each other, if you were able to use an app installed by other user, you will continue to have access to it even after their account is deleted from macOS.